# How can I add together list items that I got from a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, append

So this is a simple program I am doing for a homework assignment that I am getting stuck on somewhere in the middle.

Create a program in Python to display a menu on the kiosk at the coffee shop and then accept input from a customer concerning what item they would like to purchase.  Customers can purchase more than one item.  Test to see if the item they request is in your dictionary – if not display a message that you don’t currently carry that item.  Total the costs of all the items they wish to purchase including 9% tax to the total food cost.  Ask the customer if they would like to donate $5 to the SCC Foundation for scholarships for students.  Tally up the total amount due and display back to the customer.  Your program should accommodate multiple customers.

This is the code I have so far. I'm pretty sure my issue is with appending the list called order that I'm creating by using coffeeItems.get(itemChoice). Or it's with trying to add the elements of the list together. My brain is pretty fried right now so it could be a super simple fix I'm just not seeing.

```
import time 

coffeeItems = {"Hot Brew": 4.25, "Latte": 4.75, "Mocha": 4.99, "Cold Brew": 3.95, "Cappuccino": 4.89, "Donut": 1.50}

print("Welcome to the SCC Coffee Shop PAWS!")
print()
time.sleep(1)

print(" "*7,"Menu")
print("*"*20)
for menu in coffeeItems.items():
    print(menu)
print()
order=[]
while True:
    itemChoice = input("Please enter the item you would like to purchase or enter 'none' to exit: ")

    if itemChoice.lower() == "none":
        break
    if itemChoice not in coffeeItems.keys():
        print("Sorry, we do not currently offer that item.")
    if itemChoice in coffeeItems.keys():
        order.append([coffeeItems.get(itemChoice)])
    anotherItem = input("Would you like to purchase another item? (y/n): ")

    if anotherItem.lower() == "y":
        continue
    elif anotherItem.lower() == "n":
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid entry. Choose a valid entry or enter 'none' to continue.")
        continue
while True:
    donation=input("Would you like to donate $5 to the SCC Foundation for scholarhips for students? (y/n): ")
    if donation == "y":
        donate=5.0
        break
    elif donation =="n":
        donate=0.0
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")
        continue
tax=1.09
itemTotal= sum(order)

total= (itemTotal*tax)+donate
print(total)
```

time.sleep(3)

Comment: You want to call `.append()` without the inner `[ ]`.

Comment: Thank you  @JohnGordon. I knew it had to be something small I was overlooking.